# How can I pass login information with multiple username and password from the hashi vault when I run a playbook?

Tags: ansible, repository, artifactory, hashicorp-vault, jina

I have multiple repositories for those credentials I am keeping in hashi vault

vault:

```
Key    :        value
user1  :        password
user2  :        password
```

config.yml file

```
repo1: docker
user: user1
password: password
repo2: docker1
user: user2
password: password2
```

I have created json.j2 file for the same:

```
config.json.j2
{
"url" : "{{url}}",
"username" : "",
"password" : {{ repo_cred }},
}
```

And playbook that should that is giving me the list of username and password:
main.yml

```
tasks:
    - name: lookup user name and password
      set_fact:
        repo_cred: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', hashi_vault_params) }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      vars:
        hashi_vault_params: >-
          secret={{ hashi_vault.secret }}
          url={{ url }}
          token={{ hashi_vault }}
          ca_cert={{ hashi_vault }}
        hashi_vault:
          secret:  "test/repo_pass" 
          token:   "{{ vault_token }}"
          url:     "{{ service }}"
          ca_cert: "{{ ca_cert }}"
    - debug: msg="{{ repo_cred }}"
```

I am getting the list of username and password as output while running above task but I don't know how to make sure that the each repositories has their username and password.

Comment: Are you keeping all of your passwords in a single K/V entry, or do you have an entry for each password? What is the output of `vault list test/repo_pass` (prefix with your actual kv mount name)

Comment: I have entry for each password. The output of test/repo_pass is the directory where I am keeping all username and password.